# Algorithm that finds the N-th most frequent number in the array

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I want to write an algorithm that finds the n-th most frequent number in an array.
I have a solution but not optimal (testing numbers i've already tested)
I wonder if there is a more optimal solution?
Here is my Solution :

```
most_freq_element(a,n){
final_cnt = 0, curr_cnt = 1, final_freq_num = -1, curr_freq_num = -1;
for(i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
{
    if (a[i]!=-1){
        curr_freq_num = a[i];
        for(j =i+1; j < n; j++){
            if(curr_freq_num == a[j] && final_freq_num != curr_freq_num){
                curr_cnt++;
            }
        }
        if(final_cnt < curr_cnt){
            final_cnt = curr_cnt;
            curr_cnt = 1;
            final_freq_num = curr_freq_num;
        }
    }
}
printf("Num = %d and times = %d", final_freq_num, final_cnt);
}



nth_most_frequent_element(a,n,k){    
if(k==1){
    return most_freq_element(a,n);
}
else{ 
    for (i=0;i<k;i++){
        int most_freq_num = most_freq_element(a,n);

        for(i = 0; i < n-1; i++){
            if (a[i]==most_freq_num){
                a[i]=-1;
            }
        }
    }
    return most_freq_element(a,n);
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find the N-th most frequent number in the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10965952/find-the-n-th-most-frequent-number-in-the-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this ? Worst complexity is O(2.N.logN + k.min(k,d)), d: number of unique values in a

```
most_freq_element(a[0..n-1],n,k)
{
  count[0..k], value[0..k];   // k + 1 elements
  i, j, l;

  qsort(a, n)

  j = 0;
  l = 0;
  value[0] = a[0];
  count[0] = 1;
  for (i = 1; i < n; ++i)
  {
     if (a[i] != value[j])
     {
        if (++l > k) l = k;
        j = l;
        value[j] = a[i];
        count[j] = 0;
     }

     ++count[j];

     while (j > 0 && count[j] > count[j - 1])
     {
        swap(count[j], count[j - 1]);
        swap(value[j], value[j - 1]);
        --j;
     }
  }
  printf("Num = %d and times = %d", value[k - 1], count[k - 1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would probably make a hashmap/table, and increment each value on collision, so that the number is the key and the value is the number of collisions. Then, when you're done, aggregate it to a sorted list and grab the nth element. Would run in O(n) which is pretty optimal.

Edit: Actually, the sorting would cost n*log(n).

Comment: `aggregate it to a sorted list` would make it O(nlog(n))

Comment: You don't count the N hash map key lookups,

Comment: They're insignificant compared to nlogn. As the operations approach infinity the only term that matters is nlogn. You don't see many algorithms including every insignificant term. They just pose the term of most significance, unless there are multiple terms of equal significance

Comment: Sum{n=1..N-1}(log(N-n)) is not insignificant, since it's larger than N.

Comment: It's one iteration through the linked list for the collision count and constant-time hashmap inserts for O(n), then creating a sorted list from the entries O(nlogn + n) -> O(nlogn) and then grabbing the nth element for a max of O(n) or O(1) for a sorted array. So it's O(3n + nlogn) -> O(nlogn). 

I don't know what you're referring to.

Comment: Wait, are you under the impression that hash lookups aren't constant time? A lookup on a hash table is based on offsets given by the hash. They're constant time, so all the lookups are O(n)